# How can I get device's rotation in degrees?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, accelerometer, xamarin.essentials

I wan't to create a bubble level, gyroscope app, but Accelerometer is not giving the right values to convert to degrees.

Should I use Acceletormeter?
Or which sensor can do this for me?

For the bubble level part, I did this:

```
var x = (acceleration.X * 90f).ToString("0.0°");
var y = (acceleration.Y * 90f).ToString("0.0°");
```

And for the gyroscope part, I did this:

```
var x = (acceleration.X * 90f).ToString("0.0°");
var y = (acceleration.Z * 90f).ToString("0.0°");
```

Answer (score 0):

you're using the wrong API

> The [OrientationSensor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/orientation-sensor) class lets you monitor the orientation of a
> device in three dimensional space.

Comment: And how can I convert OrientationSensor's values into degrees. If I know right the values are between -0.707 and 0.707.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584715/how-can-i-convert-a-quaternion-to-an-angle

Comment: I implemented this and it gave me X: NaN  Y: NaN  Z: NaN

Comment: you need to show us the code you wrote and inputs and outputs you are getting